# How to mix several python scripts into a shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, virtualenv

I have a local repository and now I would like to deploy it to a docker container. I'd like to write a shell script to handle the setup of environment.

The shell script may do somethings like this in order:

1.Install virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

2.Setup a new virtual environment called `new-env`

```
virtualenv new-env
```

3.Enter the environment

```
cd new-env
```

4.activate

```
source ./bin/activate
```

5.Then we need to install dependencies with `requirements.txt` that I exported with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Notice that I put this file in the root directory.

So:

```
pip install -r ../requirements.txt
```

Is it possible to mix these python scripts into one shell script so that I could setup with just a `sh` script?  Thanks.

Comment: This may be a bit overkill wrt to your needs, but have you ever thought of using `ansible`? It is made for server deployment and can do everything you want to do in your question.

Comment: Ansible, Fabric etc. are better options over shell script for something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) is a good choice for this. Its easy to get started and can scale up as your system complexity increases. Please refer to this [tutorial](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html). A simply `yml` file to install pip, virtualenv etc. with ansible could look something like:

```
- name: download pip
  get_url: url=https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py dest=/tmp

- name: install pip
  command: "python /tmp/get-pip.py"

- name: Install virtualenv
  pip: name=virtualenv

- name: Create virtualenv path
  file: path={{ virtualenv_path }} state=directory 

- name: Install pip packages under virtualenv
  pip: requirements=/home/user/pip_list.txt virtualenv={{ virtualenv_path }}
  tags: packages
```

There's also some boilerplate setup to define variables like `virtualenv_path` & your hosts etc. Just clone a simple repo from github to get started.

Documentation is pretty good for ansible. Just keep googling for your next step and you'll find decent answers here.

Comment: Thanks ! Could not wait to check it out NOW!